# How to merge two lines of polygons?

Tags: qgis, editing, overlapping-features, coincident

In QGIS 2.6.1, I have merged two polygon shapefiles. After the merge I am facing a problem at boundaries.

[image]

So I thought of changing Polygon -> lines, manually deleting one of the lines at the boundary, and finally change line -> Polygon.

The problem is I am not able select a line between two nodes to delete; the entire polygon is getting selected when I try to select. Is there any better approach to do this?

Comment: What you're trying to do can be approached in a variety of ways, and falls under several terms. You basically want to reshape the polygons so they have coincident boundaries. I'm not familiar enough with QGIS to tell you the workflows and tools to use compared to ArcGIS where I know a number of solutions (perhaps @joseph can offer some). There are tools called Snap and Integrate in Arc. Another term for this issue is sliver polygons, and we have several questions about their elimination. The Difference tool might help. Aligning things *before* merging might also help.

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=qgis%20sliver - one of those might have a solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Node Tool** to edit your line layer:

[image: Node Tool]

When you toggle the tool, click on a vertex or the line and click the **Delete** button on your keyboard (I clicked on the line which is highlighted with the blue vertices). **Remember that a line is between 2 vertices so technically, you would be deleting 2 lines**:

[image: Select lines]

[image: Deleted lines]

To avoid this, you can modify the vertices so that another line is created. Double-click the vertice where you want to create another line and drag the cursor:

[image: Modified vertices]

Then again, select the line you want removed and hit Delete.

[image: Deleted vertices]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank u Joseph for replaying. In your example it work's because it is open vertices. Mine is closed loop(polygon->line) when I it delete the line will be deleted and then new line will be drawn with other vertices.

Comment: Ahh apologies, I see what you mean now. Hopefully others can advise you with this.